# data.table : create group ID based on group_vars and group order

Tags: r, group-by, data.table, grouping

Trying to create group identifiers for a dataset such as the one below. V1 and V2 partially identify the groups (perhaps because of a missing group variable, V3). But I also need to relly on the order of the rows, and changes in the value of V2. For instance, both groupd_id 1 and 3 have the same values of V1 and V2. The only difference between them is the fact that there is a different group in between them.

I would like to create the sequential columns (as shown in the example below):

- group_id : sequential group ID
- group_id2 : sequential group ID within V1

```
d <- data.table(V1=c(rep('A',6),rep('B',5)),
                V2=c(rep(1,2),rep(2,2),rep(1,2),c(1,1,1,2,2)),
                V4=runif(11),
                group_id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5),
                group_id_within_V1=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,2,2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
d <- data.table(V1=c(rep('A',6),rep('B',5)),
    V2=c(rep(1,2),rep(2,2),rep(1,2),c(1,1,1,2,2)),
    V4=runif(11))
d[, group_id := rleid(V1, V2)][, 
    group_id_within_V1 := group_id - min(group_id) + 1L, .(V1)]
```